# Can we programmatically insert text in UIAlertView's textfield, iOS7

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitextfield, uialertview

Can we programmatically insert text in UIAlertView's textfield, iOS7

Created UIAlertView with textinput in IOS7.
Can anyone help me with "inserting text programatically in textfield"?

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully this will give answer for your question.

```
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
            alertView.delegate = self;
            alertView.title = @"Enter Info";
            alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
            [alertView addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
            [alertView addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];

            [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text = @"My Text";

            [alertView show];
```

Comment: Tried with this, But this doesn't helped.

Comment: Also tried with this code too, But fails...                           for (id view in [myAlertView subviews]){
        if ([view isMemberOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)view;
            textField.text = @"chaitu";
            NSLog(@"%@", textField.text);
            
        }
    }

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using this code

```
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"whatever you like" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle=UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alert textFieldAtIndex:0].text=@"Hello";
[alert show];
```

and result will be like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use like this..

```
 UIAlertView* av = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
                    [av setDelegate:self];
                    [av setTitle:@"Hi"];
                    [av setMessage:nil];
                    [av addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
                    [av addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];

                    av.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
                    [av textFieldAtIndex:0].text = @"Text";
```

Comment: Is any different between your answer and @user3097889's answer?

Comment: Thanks Dharmbir Choudhary

Comment: @mani There is no difference between them. But dear at the same time we post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use text property to set text inside textfield.

```
textFiled.text = @"YOUR TEXT";
```

Comment: He asking about `How to set text on textField which is placed inside alertView`?

Comment: this is for IOS 6. But for IOS7 ? Textfield is given along with Alertview